# Malook Shatak (मलूक शतक)

Tags: rama, sita, ramanandacharya, malookacharyaastakam, ananda-bhashya

Complete **Malook Shatak**

> Written by *Malook Das* also with its transliteration.

Answer (score 0):

Malook Shatak By Malook Das Ji -

marakata maṇi sama śyāma hai śrī sītāpati rūpa ।
kōṭi madana sakucāta lakhi namai 'malūka' anūpa ॥1॥

kaha 'malūka' śrīrāma hī dharmōddhārana kāja ।
śrīmadrāmānanda bhē bhāṣyakāra yatirāja ॥2॥

jagadguru rāmānandajī ācāryana śiratāja ।
tinahiṃ 'malūkā' namata hai jaya jaya śrīyatirāja ॥3॥

kaha 'malūka' prasthāna traya bhāṣya racyō ānanda ।
śrīvaiṣṇava mata kamala ravi svāmī rāmānanda ॥4॥

jinakī anupama kṛpā sē tattva parayō pahicāna ।
una śrīgurupada padma kā dharata 'malūkā' dhyāna ॥5॥

vēdāntasiddhānta —
tattva viśiṣṭādvaita hai yahī vēda-siddhānta ।
kahai 'malūkā' lakhi parai guru kī kṛpā abhrānta ॥6॥

jīva prakṛti īśvara inhīṃ tīna tattva kā jñāna ।
āvaśyaka hai mōkṣa maha~-kahai 'malūkā' tāna ॥7॥

ātmā —
jñānāśraya hai ātmā dēhēndriya nahiṃ prāna ।
kahai 'malūkā' nitya aru nirvikāra tēhi jāna ॥8॥

kahai 'malūkā' rāma kē yē śarīra aru śēṣa ।
svaprakāśa aṇu jīva haiṃ dhārya niyāmya aśēṣa ॥9॥

sadā parāśrita jīva haiṃ rāma sadaiva svatantra ।
kahai 'malūkā' bhrānta jō jīvahiṃ kahēṃ svatantra ॥10॥

tattvamasi —
sadā prakāryadvaita kō kahai tattvamasi-vākya ।
nāhiṃ prakārādvaita yaha kahata 'malūkā' vākya ॥11॥

sadā prakārī rāma haiṃ cidacid dēha prakāra ।
'yasyātmā' ityādi śruti kahaiṃ 'malūkā' sāra ॥12॥

tat pada kahai parēśakōṃ kahai 'malūkā' jāna ।
tvaddēhī tvaṃ pada kahēṃ dōu prabhu-aikya bakhāna ॥13॥

nityapadasthita īśa hī antaryāmī hōya ।
nāma rūpa vyākaraṇa hita ēka 'malūkā' dōya ॥14॥

jīva ajña sarvajña prabhu kēhi vidhi duinauṃ ēka ।
kahai 'malūkā' bhrānta jō jīva brahma kahēṃ ēka ‌15॥

sāmānādhikaraṇya nahiṃ banai tattvamasi ṭhaura ।
jīva brahma kē bhēda bina kahai 'malūkā' aura ॥16॥

sāmānādhikaraṇyārtha —
bhēda pravṛttinimitta kā ēka artha puni hōya ।
sāmānādhikaraṇya taha~ kaha 'malūka' saba kōya ॥17॥

tat tvaṃ pada kī lakṣaṇā cētana mēṃ hī jāna ।
kahata 'malūkā' asa kabahu~ kahū~ na nara matimān ॥18॥

anvaya aru tātparya kī anupapatti jaba hōya ।
tabahi 'malūkā' lakṣaṇā mānata hai saba kōya ॥19॥

kēhi vidhi dui kāraṇa binā yahā~ lakṣaṇā hōya ।
kahaiṃ 'malūkā' kārya kahu~ bina kāraṇa hī hōya? ॥20॥

jīvabrahma-bhēda —
jīvapanāyuta brahma kē bhēdavān nahiṃ jīva ।
vastupanā sē ghaṭa sadṛśa sunahu 'malūkā' jīva ॥21॥

kaha 'malūka' tuma yaha kahau bhēda kahā~ suprasiddha ।
jīva bīca taba bādha hō nahīṃ tō sādhya asiddha ॥22॥

cētanapanasē mukti maha~ prabhu sē jīva abhinna ।
brahma sadṛśa asa vacana suni hōta 'malūkā' khinna ॥23॥

sōpādhika yaha hētu hai bhavakartṛtva upādhi ।
kahata 'malūka' prakāśapana advaitina kaha~ vyādhi ॥24॥

pakṣa tathā dṛṣṭānta yadi bhinna hōya~ taba bādha ।
kahata 'malūkā' bhēda bina udāharaṇa nahiṃ sādha ॥25॥

ātmasvarūpa —
gati āgati utkrānti yē tīna jīva kī hōya ।
kaha 'malūka' tēhi hētu sē nāhiṃ jīva vibhu hōya ॥26॥

jīva karmavaśa gahata haiṃ kōrī kuṃjara dēha ।
tātē madhyama māna nahiṃ kaha 'malūka' sasnēha ॥27॥

saṃkōcādika kē bhayē hōvē jīva vināśa ।
avayavavālī vastu kā hōta 'malūkā' nāśa ॥28॥

abhyāgata bina kiyē kā kṛta kā hōya vināśa ।
tēhisē kahata 'malūka' hai ātmā hai avināśa ॥29॥

kaha 'malūka' yaha jīva aṇu hṛdaya bīca hai thāna ।
dīpa prabhā sama jñāna sē śira pīḍa़ādika jāna ॥30॥

ātmā tathā jñāna kā bhēda —
jñānarūpa hai ātmā dharma jñāna sē bhinna ।
pratyakūpana aru parākūpana sē 'malūka' dōu bhinna ॥31॥

'maiṃ jānauṃ' paratīti yaha sārvajanika nirbādha ।
jñātā bhinna 'malūka' yaha pratīti jñānahiṃ sādha ॥32॥

jīvaikya-nirāsa —
kōī kahatē ātmā saba dēhana maha~ ēka ।
bhinna bhinna saba dēha maha~ kahata 'malūka' anēka ॥33॥

kaha 'malūka' saba dēha kē jīva hōya~ yadi ēka ।
ēka kāla maha~ duḥkha ika sukha bhōgaiṃ kimi ēka ॥34॥

dēha bhēda sē jā kahahu sukhī dukhī kā bhēda ।
kyōṃ na 'malūkā' saubharihiṃ sukha-dukha tanu kē bhēda ॥35॥

jīvabhēda —
baddha mukta aru nitya yaha jīva bhēda haiṃ tīna ।
kaha 'malūka' anyatra puni bahuta bhēda haiṃ kīna ॥36॥

acit tattva —
miśra śuddha sat kāla yaha acit bhēda haiṃ tīna ।
kaha 'malūka' caubīsa taha~ miśra-bhēda haiṃ kīna ॥37॥

kaha 'malūka' prakṛtī mahat ahaṅkāra traya jāna ।
ēkādaśa indriyana kā sātvika kāraṇa māna ॥38॥

tāmasa sē tanmātra aru paṃca bhūta hū hōya ।
kaha 'malūka' rājasaḥ punaḥ ubhaya sahāyaka hōya ॥39॥

śuddhasatva athavā nityavibhūti —
kahata 'malūkā' śuddhasat nityavibhūtihi jāna ।
“tadvipṇōḥ paramaṃ padam” taha~ yaha śrutihi pramāna ॥40॥

kāla —
bhūta bhaviṣyat ādi saba vyavahārana kā mūla ।
kahata 'malūkā' kāla hai kālahiṃ bhūli na bhūla ॥41॥

jaganmithyātva-nirāsa —
kaha 'malūka' jhūṭhē kahahiṃ jhūṭhī aisī bāta ।
brahma satya aru jaga mṛṣā paramāratha nahiṃ tāta ॥42॥

sarva viśēṣaṇa sē rahita brahma ēka advaita ।
brahmasatyapana hētu taba kaha 'malūka' kimi dēta ॥43॥

dṛśyapanahu kē hētu jō jaga kaha~ mṛṣā bakhāna ।
kaha 'malūka' tēhi hētu kō sōpādhika pahicāna ॥44॥

vyāpti kaunasī rīti sē gahī batāvahu aura ।
mithyāpana aru dṛśyapana kī 'malūka' kēhi ṭhaura ॥46॥

śukti rajata thala kahahu tō nahiṃ 'malūka' nistāra ।
dēkhahu ānaॅṃdabhāṣya kā catuḥsūtra-vistāra ॥47॥

śuktirajata yahi jñāna kā viṣaya satya pahicāna ।
hai yathārtha vijñāna saba kahata 'malūkā' jāna ॥48॥

īśvaratattva —
sirajana saṃhārana tathā jaga kē pālanahāra ।
kahai 'malūkā' rāma hī īśa sarva-ādhāra ॥50॥

mōkṣa kāma dharmārtha kē dēnahāra śrīrāma ।
divya dēha śubha guṇana kē haiṃ 'malūka' śubha dhāma ॥51॥

dēha rūpa aru guṇana sē vyāpaka prabhu saba ṭhaura ।
kaha 'malūka' saba vastu kē bāhara bhītara aura ॥52॥

kaha 'malūka' parabhakti sē tuṣṭa hōya~ śrīrāma ।
nija bhaktahiṃ sāyujya taba dēta akhilapati rāma ॥53॥

para vyūha aru vibhava aru antaryāmī māna ।
kaha 'malūka' arcātanuhiṃ hari pañcama thiti jāna ॥54॥

para sākētanivāsa haiṃ avatārī śrīrāma ।
kaha 'malūka' parikaranayuta vaidēhī-abhirāma ॥55॥

vāsudēva ityādi kaha~ caturyūha pahicāna ।
kaha 'malūka' matsyādi kaha~ vibhava rūpa sē māna ॥56॥

antaryāmī ramē jasa mēha~dī lōhita rūpa ।
kaha 'malūka' avadhādi maha~ arcāmūrti anupa ॥57॥

śrīavadhapurī —
hanumadādi bharatādi saha tathā jānakī sātha ।
kaha 'malūka' jaha~ kīna prabhu nija līlā raghunātha ॥58॥

avadhapurī sō śrēṣṭhatama mōkṣadāni sukhakhāni ।
mahimā tāsu 'malūka' puni kō kavi sakai bakhāni ॥59॥

śrīsarayū līlā līlā-dhāma kī lalita jahā~ vikhyāta ।
kaha 'malūka' surasarita tēhi sarayuhiṃ lakhi sakucāti ॥60॥

pañca saṃskāra —
ūrdhvapuṇḍra sē hōta sukha mōkṣa tathā dukhanāśa ।
kaha 'malūka' sō puṇḍra lakhi yama-gaṇa hōta hatāśa ॥61॥

dhanurbāṇa-aṃkita bhujā jō jana hōta 'malūka' ।
sarvapāpa sē mukta tēhi para pada milata acūka ॥62॥

bhagavat pūrva 'malūka' puni nāma anta maha~ dāsa ।
mukti milata taba, śāstra kaha jīva mātra haridāsa ॥63॥

tulasī bina nahiṃ hari-bhajana-adhikārī hō jīva ।
kaha malūka ati śrēṣṭha hai tulasī bhūṣitagrīva ॥64॥

jimi saba vēdana bīca hai sāmavēda śiratāja ।
timi malūka saba maṃtra maha~ rāmamaṃtra adhirāja ॥65॥

dharma —
ēka dharma hī jāta hai marē jīva kē sātha ।
anya 'malūkā' naṣṭa hōṃ saba śarīra kē sātha ॥66॥

catura varṇa maha~ hōta hai brāhmaṇa yathā mahān ।
saba mahaॅṃ vaiṣṇava dharma timi mahat 'malūka' bakhāna ॥67॥

viṣṇu-bhakta kaha~ jē kahahiṃ kaha 'malūka' durvākya ।
parahiṃ naraka sukhahīna hvai kahata śāstra asa vākya ॥68॥

parahita sama kōu dharma nahiṃ hiṃsā sama nahiṃ pāpa ।
dharma karahiṃ vaiṣṇava sadā kaha 'malūka' nahiṃ pāpa ॥69॥

indrādika saba dēva aru gaṃgādika saba tīrtha ।
kaha 'malūka' taha~ vasata haiṃ jaha~ vaiṣṇava-pada-tīrthaṃ ॥70॥

nija varṇāśrama-karma sē arcahiṃ jō siyarāma ।
kaha 'malūka' sō lahata haiṃ akṣaya sukha para-dhāma ॥71॥

rāmanāma —
kaha 'malūka' śatasandhiyuta jarjara girata śarīra ।
bhēṣaja taji rasavara piyahu nitya nāma raghuvīra ॥72॥

rāma māhiṃ rami rāhata hū~ rāma rāma iti nāma ।
kaha 'malūka' śiva kahata asa sahasanāma sama rāma ॥73॥

rāmanāma sama āna nahiṃ kali mu~ha sugama upāya ।
kaha 'malūka' yōgādi maha~ mana nahiṃ thira gati pāya ॥74॥

santōṣa —
kyōṃ 'malūka' paci marata hō burē pēṭa kē hēta ।
rāma jīva kē janmatahi mātathanana paya dēta ॥75॥

ajagara karai na cākarī pakṣī karai na kāma ।
'dāsa malūkā' kahata hai saba kē dātā rāma ॥76॥

bhakti —
karma-yōgahū vyartha hō jñāna-yōga hō rōga ।
kaha 'malūka' hari-bhakti bina miṭai na bhavakō bhōga ॥77॥

ēka ananyā bhakti maha~ mukti-dāna kī śakti ।
kahata 'malūkā' santa jana nava prakāra kī bhakti ॥78॥

navadhā bhakti —
śrīsītāpati carita kā śravaṇa prēma sē māna ।
kahata 'malūkā' prathama yaha 'śravaṇabhakti' ura āna ॥79॥

nāma sahita raghunātha kā prēma sahita guṇagāna ।
kahata 'malūkā' dūsarī 'kīrtana bhakti' sujāna‌ ॥80॥

'sumirana bhakti' kahata haiṃ tīsari sunahu malūka ।
niśidina hari-guṇa-dhāma kā sumirana karai acūka ॥81॥

daśarathanṛpa-suta-caraṇa-raja jaḍa़hiṃ karai caitanya ।
sōi 'pada-sēvana-bhakti' hai cauthi 'malūkā' dhanya ॥82॥

kauśalyā kē lāla kī bahuvidhi arcā jōya ।
paścama 'arcana' nāma sō bhakti 'malūkā' hōya ॥83॥

ṣaṣṭhī 'vandana' bhakti hai kaha 'malūka' svara ū~ca ।
prabhu-pada-vandana-bhakti hai saba yajñana sē ū~ca ॥84॥

bhakti saptamī rāmakī dāsya nāma kī hōya ।
kaha 'malūka' hari-dāsa bina nahiṃ tārata kula kōya ॥85॥

bandhu sadṛśa vyavahāra kaha~ nara sama dēkhana hēta ।
'sakhya bhakti' aṣṭama karahiṃ jana 'malūka' kari cēta ॥86॥

'ātmasamarpaṇa' karata jana chaॉḍi sakala vidha karma ।
jimi jaṭāyu timi navama yaha bhakti 'malūkā' marma‌ ॥87॥

śravaṇa bhakti lavakuśa karē vālmīki guṇagāna ।
kaha 'malūka' sumiraṇa karē kumbhaja śiṣya sujāna ॥88॥

bharata bhāvayuta caraṇarata śabarī arcana jāna ।
kaha 'malūka' vandana punaḥ vandya vibhīṣaṇa māna ॥89॥

śrī māruta-sutadāsa aru sakhā bhayē kapirāja ।
svātmārpaka tu 'malūka' hai śrī jaṭāyu khagarāja ॥90॥

prapatti —
ēka bārahū śaraṇa hita tava hū~ imi jō yāca ।
kaha 'malūka' śrīrāma tēhi abhaya karēṃ yaha sā~ca ॥91॥

gurudēva —
jēhi sē saba brahmāṇḍa yaha kaha malūka haiṃ vyāpta ।
tēhi hari darśaka guru binā sukha na kahata jana āpta ॥92॥

kaha 'malūka' jō bhajata hai sadguru aru bhagavān ।
sōī jānai tattva jō kahatē vēda purāna ॥93॥

traya rahasya aru tattvatraya pañśca artha kā jñāna ।
kaha malūka guru sē lahahu jō cāhahu kalyāṇa ॥94॥

cāra sampradāya —
jānahu śrī sanakādi aru brahmā rudra udāra ।
kaha 'malūka' vaidika yahī sampradāya haiṃ cāra ॥95॥

rāmānandācārya jī śrī kē śubha ācārya ।
kaha 'malūka' sanakādi kē haiṃ (śrī) nimbārkācārya ॥96॥

kaha 'malūka' śrī brahma kē haiṃ śrī madhvācārya।
viṣṇu svāmi śrī rudra kē sampradāya-ācārya ॥97॥

guruparamparā-praṇāma —
śrī sītāpati ādi ma~ha madhyama rāmānanda ।
kaha 'malūka' nija-guruna kaha~ praṇamahu sadā amanda ॥98॥

kalyāṇōpadēśa —
pariśīlahu bhāṣyādi śrī sampradāya kē grantha ।
kaha 'malūka' bhava-tarana kā ihai akaṇṭaka pantha ॥99॥

kaha 'malūka' yahi dēha sē yadi cāhahu kalyāna ।
santa-saṃga aru kariya nita siya siyapatikā dhyāna ॥100॥

śrī sītāpati kṛpā sē śataka kahyōṃ suvicāri ।
kaha 'malūka' guni bhakti kari lahahu bhavya phala cāri ॥101॥

जगद्गुरु श्रीमलूकदासाचार्यविरचितं 'मलूकशतकम्'

मरकत मणि सम श्याम है श्री सीतापति रूप ।
कोटि मदन सकुचात लखि नमै 'मलूक' अनूप ॥१॥

कह 'मलूक' श्रीराम ही धर्मोद्धारन काज ।
श्रीमद्रामानन्द भे भाष्यकार यतिराज ॥२॥

जगद्गुरु रामानन्दजी आचार्यन शिरताज ।
तिनहिं 'मलूका' नमत है जय जय श्रीयतिराज ॥३॥

कह 'मलूक' प्रस्थान त्रय भाष्य रच्यो आनन्द ।
श्रीवैष्णव मत कमल रवि स्वामी रामानन्द ॥४॥

जिनकी अनुपम कृपा से तत्त्व परयो पहिचान ।
उन श्रीगुरुपद पद्म का धरत 'मलूका' ध्यान ॥५॥

वेदान्तसिद्धान्त —
तत्त्व विशिष्टाद्वैत है यही वेद-सिद्धान्त ।
कहै 'मलूका' लखि परै गुरु की कृपा अभ्रान्त ॥६॥

जीव प्रकृति ईश्वर इन्हीं तीन तत्त्व का ज्ञान ।
आवश्यक है मोक्ष महँ-कहै 'मलूका' तान ॥७॥

आत्मा —
ज्ञानाश्रय है आत्मा देहेन्द्रिय नहिं प्रान ।
कहै 'मलूका' नित्य अरु निर्विकार तेहि जान ॥८॥

कहै 'मलूका' राम के ये शरीर अरु शेष ।
स्वप्रकाश अणु जीव हैं धार्य नियाम्य अशेष ॥९॥

सदा पराश्रित जीव हैं राम सदैव स्वतन्त्र ।
कहै 'मलूका' भ्रान्त जो जीवहिं कहें स्वतन्त्र ॥१०॥

तत्त्वमसि —
सदा प्रकार्यद्वैत को कहै तत्त्वमसि-वाक्य ।
नाहिं प्रकाराद्वैत यह कहत 'मलूका' वाक्य ॥११॥

सदा प्रकारी राम हैं चिदचिद् देह प्रकार ।
'यस्यात्मा' इत्यादि श्रुति कहैं 'मलूका' सार ॥१२॥

तत् पद कहै परेशकों कहै 'मलूका' जान ।
त्वद्देही त्वं पद कहें दोउ प्रभु-ऐक्य बखान ॥१३॥

नित्यपदस्थित ईश ही अन्तर्यामी होय ।
नाम रूप व्याकरण हित एक 'मलूका' दोय ॥१४॥

जीव अज्ञ सर्वज्ञ प्रभु केहि विधि दुइनौं एक ।
कहै 'मलूका' भ्रान्त जो जीव ब्रह्म कहें एक ‌१५॥

सामानाधिकरण्य नहिं बनै तत्त्वमसि ठौर ।
जीव ब्रह्म के भेद बिन कहै 'मलूका' और ॥१६॥

सामानाधिकरण्यार्थ —
भेद प्रवृत्तिनिमित्त का एक अर्थ पुनि होय ।
सामानाधिकरण्य तहँ कह 'मलूक' सब कोय ॥१७॥

तत् त्वं पद की लक्षणा चेतन में ही जान ।
कहत 'मलूका' अस कबहुँ कहूँ न नर मतिमान् ॥१८॥

अन्वय अरु तात्पर्य की अनुपपत्ति जब होय ।
तबहि 'मलूका' लक्षणा मानत है सब कोय ॥१९॥

केहि विधि दुइ कारण बिना यहाँ लक्षणा होय ।
कहैं 'मलूका' कार्य कहुँ बिन कारण ही होय? ॥२०॥

जीवब्रह्म-भेद —
जीवपनायुत ब्रह्म के भेदवान् नहिं जीव ।
वस्तुपना से घट सदृश सुनहु 'मलूका' जीव ॥२१॥

कह 'मलूक' तुम यह कहौ भेद कहाँ सुप्रसिद्ध ।
जीव बीच तब बाध हो नहीं तो साध्य असिद्ध ॥२२॥

चेतनपनसे मुक्ति महँ प्रभु से जीव अभिन्न ।
ब्रह्म सदृश अस वचन सुनि होत 'मलूका' खिन्न ॥२३॥

सोपाधिक यह हेतु है भवकर्तृत्व उपाधि ।
कहत 'मलूक' प्रकाशपन अद्वैतिन कहँ व्याधि ॥२४॥

पक्ष तथा दृष्टान्त यदि भिन्न होयँ तब बाध ।
कहत 'मलूका' भेद बिन उदाहरण नहिं साध ॥२५॥

आत्मस्वरूप —
गति आगति उत्क्रान्ति ये तीन जीव की होय ।
कह 'मलूक' तेहि हेतु से नाहिं जीव विभु होय ॥२६॥

जीव कर्मवश गहत हैं कोरी कुंजर देह ।
ताते मध्यम मान नहिं कह 'मलूक' सस्नेह ॥२७॥

संकोचादिक के भये होवे जीव विनाश ।
अवयववाली वस्तु का होत 'मलूका' नाश ॥२८॥

अभ्यागत बिन किये का कृत का होय विनाश ।
तेहिसे कहत 'मलूक' है आत्मा है अविनाश ॥२९॥

कह 'मलूक' यह जीव अणु हृदय बीच है थान ।
दीप प्रभा सम ज्ञान से शिर पीड़ादिक जान ॥३०॥

आत्मा तथा ज्ञान का भेद —
ज्ञानरूप है आत्मा धर्म ज्ञान से भिन्न ।
प्रत्यकूपन अरु पराकूपन से 'मलूक' दोउ भिन्न ॥३१॥

'मैं जानौं' परतीति यह सार्वजनिक निर्बाध ।
ज्ञाता भिन्न 'मलूक' यह प्रतीति ज्ञानहिं साध ॥३२॥

जीवैक्य-निरास —
कोई कहते आत्मा सब देहन महँ एक ।
भिन्न भिन्न सब देह महँ कहत 'मलूक' अनेक ॥३३॥

कह 'मलूक' सब देह के जीव होयँ यदि एक ।
एक काल महँ दुःख इक सुख भोगैं किमि एक ॥३४॥

देह भेद से जा कहहु सुखी दुखी का भेद ।
क्यों न 'मलूका' सौभरिहिं सुख-दुख तनु के भेद ॥३५॥

जीवभेद —
बद्ध मुक्त अरु नित्य यह जीव भेद हैं तीन ।
कह 'मलूक' अन्यत्र पुनि बहुत भेद हैं कीन ॥३६॥

अचित् तत्त्व —
मिश्र शुद्ध सत् काल यह अचित् भेद हैं तीन ।
कह 'मलूक' चौबीस तहँ मिश्र-भेद हैं कीन ॥३७॥

कह 'मलूक' प्रकृती महत् अहङ्कार त्रय जान ।
एकादश इन्द्रियन का सात्विक कारण मान ॥३८॥

तामस से तन्मात्र अरु पंच भूत हू होय ।
कह 'मलूक' राजसः पुनः उभय सहायक होय ॥३९॥

शुद्धसत्व अथवा नित्यविभूति —
कहत 'मलूका' शुद्धसत् नित्यविभूतिहि जान ।
“तद्विप्णोः परमं पदम्” तहँ यह श्रुतिहि प्रमान ॥४०॥

काल —
भूत भविष्यत् आदि सब व्यवहारन का मूल ।
कहत 'मलूका' काल है कालहिं भूलि न भूल ॥४१॥

जगन्मिथ्यात्व-निरास —
कह 'मलूक' झूठे कहहिं झूठी ऐसी बात ।
ब्रह्म सत्य अरु जग मृषा परमारथ नहिं तात ॥४२॥

सर्व विशेषण से रहित ब्रह्म एक अद्वैत ।
ब्रह्मसत्यपन हेतु तब कह 'मलूक' किमि देत ॥४३॥

दृश्यपनहु के हेतु जो जग कहँ मृषा बखान ।
कह 'मलूक' तेहि हेतु को सोपाधिक पहिचान ॥४४॥

व्याप्ति कौनसी रीति से गही बतावहु और ।
मिथ्यापन अरु दृश्यपन की 'मलूक' केहि ठौर ॥४६॥

शुक्ति रजत थल कहहु तो नहिं 'मलूक' निस्तार ।
देखहु आनॅंदभाष्य का चतुःसूत्र-विस्तार ॥४७॥

शुक्तिरजत यहि ज्ञान का विषय सत्य पहिचान ।
है यथार्थ विज्ञान सब कहत 'मलूका' जान ॥४८॥

ईश्वरतत्त्व —
सिरजन संहारन तथा जग के पालनहार ।
कहै 'मलूका' राम ही ईश सर्व-आधार ॥५०॥

मोक्ष काम धर्मार्थ के देनहार श्रीराम ।
दिव्य देह शुभ गुणन के हैं 'मलूक' शुभ धाम ॥५१॥

देह रूप अरु गुणन से व्यापक प्रभु सब ठौर ।
कह 'मलूक' सब वस्तु के बाहर भीतर और ॥५२॥

कह 'मलूक' परभक्ति से तुष्ट होयँ श्रीराम ।
निज भक्तहिं सायुज्य तब देत अखिलपति राम ॥५३॥

पर व्यूह अरु विभव अरु अन्तर्यामी मान ।
कह 'मलूक' अर्चातनुहिं हरि पञ्चम थिति जान ॥५४॥

पर साकेतनिवास हैं अवतारी श्रीराम ।
कह 'मलूक' परिकरनयुत वैदेही-अभिराम ॥५५॥

वासुदेव इत्यादि कहँ चतुर्यूह पहिचान ।
कह 'मलूक' मत्स्यादि कहँ विभव रूप से मान ॥५६॥

अन्तर्यामी रमे जस मेहँदी लोहित रूप ।
कह 'मलूक' अवधादि महँ अर्चामूर्ति अनुप ॥५७॥

श्रीअवधपुरी —
हनुमदादि भरतादि सह तथा जानकी साथ ।
कह 'मलूक' जहँ कीन प्रभु निज लीला रघुनाथ ॥५८॥

अवधपुरी सो श्रेष्ठतम मोक्षदानि सुखखानि ।
महिमा तासु 'मलूक' पुनि को कवि सकै बखानि ॥६०॥

श्रीसरयू लीला लीला-धाम की ललित जहाँ विख्यात ।
कह 'मलूक' सुरसरित तेहि सरयुहिं लखि सकुचाति ॥५८॥

पञ्च संस्कार —
ऊर्ध्वपुण्ड्र से होत सुख मोक्ष तथा दुखनाश ।
कह 'मलूक' सो पुण्ड्र लखि यम-गण होत हताश ॥६१॥

धनुर्बाण-अंकित भुजा जो जन होत 'मलूक' ।
सर्वपाप से मुक्त तेहि पर पद मिलत अचूक ॥६२॥

भगवत् पूर्व 'मलूक' पुनि नाम अन्त महँ दास ।
मुक्ति मिलत तब, शास्त्र कह जीव मात्र हरिदास ॥६३॥

तुलसी बिन नहिं हरि-भजन-अधिकारी हो जीव ।
कह मलूक अति श्रेष्ठ है तुलसी भूषितग्रीव ॥६४॥

जिमि सब वेदन बीच है सामवेद शिरताज ।
तिमि मलूक सब मंत्र महँ राममंत्र अधिराज ॥६५॥

धर्म —
एक धर्म ही जात है मरे जीव के साथ ।
अन्य 'मलूका' नष्ट हों सब शरीर के साथ ॥६६॥

चतुर वर्ण महँ होत है ब्राह्मण यथा महान् ।
सब महॅं वैष्णव धर्म तिमि महत् 'मलूक' बखान ॥६७॥

विष्णु-भक्त कहँ जे कहहिं कह 'मलूक' दुर्वाक्य ।
परहिं नरक सुखहीन ह्वै कहत शास्त्र अस वाक्य ॥६८॥

परहित सम कोउ धर्म नहिं हिंसा सम नहिं पाप ।
धर्म करहिं वैष्णव सदा कह 'मलूक' नहिं पाप ॥६९॥

इन्द्रादिक सब देव अरु गंगादिक सब तीर्थ ।
कह 'मलूक' तहँ वसत हैं जहँ वैष्णव-पद-तीर्थं ॥७०॥

निज वर्णाश्रम-कर्म से अर्चहिं जो सियराम ।
कह 'मलूक' सो लहत हैं अक्षय सुख पर-धाम ॥७१॥

रामनाम —
कह 'मलूक' शतसन्धियुत जर्जर गिरत शरीर ।
भेषज तजि रसवर पियहु नित्य नाम रघुवीर ॥७२॥

राम माहिं रमि राहत हूँ राम राम इति नाम ।
कह 'मलूक' शिव कहत अस सहसनाम सम राम ॥७३॥

रामनाम सम आन नहिं कलि मुँह सुगम उपाय ।
कह 'मलूक' योगादि महँ मन नहिं थिर गति पाय ॥७४॥

सन्तोष —
क्यों 'मलूक' पचि मरत हो बुरे पेट के हेत ।
राम जीव के जन्मतहि मातथनन पय देत ॥७५॥

अजगर करै न चाकरी पक्षी करै न काम ।
'दास मलूका' कहत है सब के दाता राम ॥७६॥

भक्ति —
कर्म-योगहू व्यर्थ हो ज्ञान-योग हो रोग ।
कह 'मलूक' हरि-भक्ति बिन मिटै न भवको भोग ॥७७॥

एक अनन्या भक्ति महँ मुक्ति-दान की शक्ति ।
कहत 'मलूका' सन्त जन नव प्रकार की भक्ति ॥७८॥

नवधा भक्ति —
श्रीसीतापति चरित का श्रवण प्रेम से मान ।
कहत 'मलूका' प्रथम यह 'श्रवणभक्ति' उर आन ॥७९॥

नाम सहित रघुनाथ का प्रेम सहित गुणगान ।
कहत 'मलूका' दूसरी 'कीर्तन भक्ति' सुजान‌ ॥८०॥

'सुमिरन भक्ति' कहत हैं तीसरि सुनहु मलूक ।
निशिदिन हरि-गुण-धाम का सुमिरन करै अचूक ॥८१॥

दशरथनृप-सुत-चरण-रज जड़हिं करै चैतन्य ।
सोइ 'पद-सेवन-भक्ति' है चौथि 'मलूका' धन्य ॥८२॥

कौशल्या के लाल की बहुविधि अर्चा जोय ।
पश्चम 'अर्चन' नाम सो भक्ति 'मलूका' होय ॥८३॥

षष्ठी 'वन्दन' भक्ति है कह 'मलूक' स्वर ऊँच ।
प्रभु-पद-वन्दन-भक्ति है सब यज्ञन से ऊँच ॥८४॥

भक्ति सप्तमी रामकी दास्य नाम की होय ।
कह 'मलूक' हरि-दास बिन नहिं तारत कुल कोय ॥८५॥

बन्धु सदृश व्यवहार कहँ नर सम देखन हेत ।
'सख्य भक्ति' अष्टम करहिं जन 'मलूक' करि चेत ॥८६॥

'आत्मसमर्पण' करत जन छॉडि सकल विध कर्म ।
जिमि जटायु तिमि नवम यह भक्ति 'मलूका' मर्म‌ ॥८७॥

श्रवण भक्ति लवकुश करे वाल्मीकि गुणगान ।
कह 'मलूक' सुमिरण करे कुम्भज शिष्य सुजान ॥८८॥

भरत भावयुत चरणरत शबरी अर्चन जान ।
कह 'मलूक' वन्दन पुनः वन्द्य विभीषण मान ॥८९॥

श्री मारुत-सुतदास अरु सखा भये कपिराज ।
स्वात्मार्पक तु 'मलूक' है श्री जटायु खगराज ॥९०॥

प्रपत्ति —
एक बारहू शरण हित तव हूँ इमि जो याच ।
कह 'मलूक' श्रीराम तेहि अभय करें यह साँच ॥९१॥

गुरुदेव —
जेहि से सब ब्रह्माण्ड यह कह मलूक हैं व्याप्त ।
तेहि हरि दर्शक गुरु बिना सुख न कहत जन आप्त ॥९२॥

कह 'मलूक' जो भजत है सद्गुरु अरु भगवान् ।
सोई जानै तत्त्व जो कहते वेद पुरान ॥९३॥

त्रय रहस्य अरु तत्त्वत्रय पञ्श्च अर्थ का ज्ञान ।
कह मलूक गुरु से लहहु जो चाहहु कल्याण ॥९४॥

चार सम्प्रदाय —
जानहु श्री सनकादि अरु ब्रह्मा रुद्र उदार ।
कह 'मलूक' वैदिक यही सम्प्रदाय हैं चार ॥९५॥

रामानन्दाचार्य जी श्री के शुभ आचार्य ।
कह 'मलूक' सनकादि के हैं (श्री) निम्बार्काचार्य ॥९६॥

कह 'मलूक' श्री ब्रह्म के हैं श्री मध्वाचार्य।
विष्णु स्वामि श्री रुद्र के सम्प्रदाय-आचार्य ॥९७॥

गुरुपरम्परा-प्रणाम —
श्री सीतापति आदि मँह मध्यम रामानन्द ।
कह 'मलूक' निज-गुरुन कहँ प्रणमहु सदा अमन्द ॥९८॥

कल्याणोपदेश —
परिशीलहु भाष्यादि श्री सम्प्रदाय के ग्रन्थ ।
कह 'मलूक' भव-तरन का इहै अकण्टक पन्थ ॥९९॥

कह 'मलूक' यहि देह से यदि चाहहु कल्यान ।
सन्त-संग अरु करिय नित सिय सियपतिका ध्यान ॥१००॥

श्री सीतापति कृपा से शतक कह्यों सुविचारि ।
कह 'मलूक' गुनि भक्ति करि लहहु भव्य फल चारि ॥१०१॥

Comment: We have many times told you this is an English site. While quoting the verses in the respective language (in which it was written), is fine, but we will also need to add English translation to it. Please edit and add English translation to it.